# Как протестировать добавление элемента в список C#? NUnit

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, nunit

Доброго времени суток!

Никак не могу догадаться, как же протестировать следующий блок в коде с помощью тестов `NUnit`:

```
public static class List  //Абстрактный класс работы со списком на основе двух типовых элементов
{
    public static void Add(ref SimpleElm firstElm, string value)  //Добавить в список простой элемент
    {
        if (value == "") return;
        SimpleElm newElm = new SimpleElm(value);
        if (firstElm == null)
        {
            firstElm = newElm;
            return;
        }
        SimpleElm elm = firstElm;
        while (elm.next != null)
            elm = elm.next;
        elm.next = newElm;
    }
}
```

Собственно сам `SimpleElm` ниже:

```
public class SimpleElm // Простой класс
{
    public string Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public SimpleElm next;
    public SimpleElm(string value = "")
    {
        Value = value;
        next = null;
    }
    public SimpleElm this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index < 0) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            var item = this;
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                if (item.next != null) 
                    item = item.next;
            return item;
        }
        set
        {
            if (index < 0) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            var item = this;
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                if (item.next != null)
                    item = item.next;
            item = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а в чем, собственно, проблема? напишите тесты на те случаи, которые соответствуют if-ам в коде добавления. вы пробовали их писать? что именно не получилось?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае, поскольку в классе SimpleElm есть некое поведение в индексаторе, то надо начать пожалуй что с модульных тестов для класса SimpleElm. И здесь прежде чем двинуться дальше хотелось бы понять что вы хотели бы чтобы происходило в индексаторе, потому что если мы сейчас набросаем вот такой тест и запустим его с вашим кодом, то он успешно выполнится:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace so.list.test
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class SimpleElmTest
    {
        private SimpleElm list;

        [SetUp]
        public void setUp()
        {
            this.list = new SimpleElm();
        }

        [Test]
        public void after_construction_test()
        {
            Assert.IsNull(this.list.Value);
            Assert.IsNull(this.list.Next);
        }

        [Test]
        public void set_Next_with_accessor_test()
        {
            SimpleElm next = new SimpleElm("Second");
            this.list.Next = next;

            Assert.AreEqual(next, this.list.Next);
            Assert.AreEqual(next.Value, this.list.Next.Value);
        }

        [Test]
        public void set_first_Next_with_indexer_test()
        {
            SimpleElm next = new SimpleElm("Second");
            this.list[1] = next;

            Assert.IsNull(this.list.Next);
        }

        [Test]
        public void set_third_Next_with_indexer_test()
        {
            SimpleElm next = new SimpleElm("Second");
            this.list[3] = next;

            Assert.IsNull(this.list.Next);
        }

    }
}
```

И вопрос здесь, вы действительно предполагали что оно будет именно так работать?

Comment: Не поверите, но это именно то что мне было нужно:) Спасибо!